# Injecting ILogger using Ninject, Log4Net, and Nancy

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, log4net, nancy

I am currently working with an application that uses Ninject, Log4Net, and Nancy.

The issue I am having is determining the best way to persist the Log4Net configuration provided by the Web.config to all injected instances of ILogger.

Some context:

Within this application, we construct a single ninject `StandardKernel`, which automatically loads the `Log4NetModule` provided by `Ninject.Extensions.Logging`

Our Nancy Bootstrapper class inherits from `NinjectNancyBootstrapper` using [this project](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject)

Using the above approach, we are able to successfully resolve the following property:

```
/// <summary>
/// Injected Logger
/// </summary>
[Inject]
public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
```

That relies on a Log4Net config provided within our Web.config.

Just prior to the creation of the static `StandardKernel`, we are executing the XmlConfigurator:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
_kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

From my understanding, this configurator should only need to be called one time in the application (which admittedly may be incorrect), prior to the creation of any ILogger instances. Upon starting my application, the first instance of the ILogger that is injected has the contained appenders that I would expect. Every subsequent call still successfully resolves the dependency, but is missing appenders present for the first configuration. Is there an intended behavior here that the `XmlConfigurator` will only apply to the first ILogger created? While this would definitely work in the case of using a single ILogger for the entire application, I would like at least one per type.

One of my initial attempts at solving this issue was attaching the XMLConfigurator into the `RequestStartup` method, but adds quite a lot of overhead to our API calls (nearly doubling the response time).

Maybe I'm approaching this problem entirely wrong, but I would like to know if anyone has suggestions and/or a solution to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to register `ILogger` as a singleton service in `Ninject`
Something like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ILogger>.To<LoggerConstructor>().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but in this case I was hoping to get a single logger instance (either 1 per type or 1 per request without incurring the XML Loading overhead). I ended up being able to run the XML Load a single time. It appears the issue boiled down to a child container being spawned each request. I added some custom logic to cause my nancy request handler to retrieve the logging dependency from the parent IoC container and it seems it now has the desired behavior